# Detecting checking/unchecking of rules in a rule-based rendering using PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, rule-based

Is it possible to programmatically detect checking/unchecking **changes** of a rule in a rule-based rendering ? I found no indication of existing signals ..

I got lost reading [QgsVectorLayerRenderer Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerRenderer.html) ...

Seeking preferably a solution for QGIS 3.x

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Comment: well ... i understand your comment but i'm stuck at the very beginning ... i've read the documentation of the class and found no usable ... i've maybe skipped some information but in fact i haven't found any signal related with that clas ...so i'm a bit lost and searching for a starting point ...